# How to identify a Tile without using its name attribute

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap

In the newly added Tilemap system, the `TileBase` and `Tile` have no `tag` attribute and it is then not possible to identify them by anything else than their `name` attribute which is not very practical. It is however said in the documentation of `TileBase` :

> Inherit from this to implement your custom tile to be placed in a Tilemap component.

I guess it can be used to create our own tile system but then I can't find a way to use this new class in the tilemap instead of the basic `Tile` class. How can I use this inheritance to create my own Tiles ?

Answer (score 2):

Tiles only have one instance, you can get these from the tile palette. The tiles inside the tile maps are the same, so if you have a tile instance, you can simply use

```
tilemap.GetTile(position) == tile
```

To create your own tiles, you need to inherit from `TileBase` and override some of the methods (at least `GetTileData` and `RefreshTile`, the latter one should also refresh the surrounding tiles if necessary)

Comment: Oh okay each tile has only one instance. I have 4 different types of tiles, let's I want to give each tile an ID (as a string), let's say "Lava", "Water", "Sand" and "Forest". How can I do that because I don't create the tiles myself, they are created when I paint them on the grid.

Comment: @Shashimee You can very easily create a custom tile with a tag attribute

Comment: For some examples of custom tiles, check out the repo https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras/tree/master/Assets/Tilemap/Tiles